# ABCpdf 64-bit core engine version 10105 is older than ABCpdf .NET version 10.1.0.7

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf.net to merge few pdf files. but I am getting below error while creating object of Doc class...

> ABCpdf 64-bit core engine version 10105 is older than ABCpdf .NET version 10.1.0.7.

There is no other error information available in exception snapshot. Code which is throwing error...

```
Doc mergedPdf = new Doc();
```

I am using ABCPdf.net version 10.1.0.5 and have no reference of ABCpdf.net version 10.1.0.7.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. I found the cause. Previously my solution was using 10.1.0.7 version that was downgraded to old version 10.1.0.5 due to some business requirements. ABCpdf.net version 10.1.0.7 binaries were copied to bin/debug folder and forcing this exception to be thrown.

Somehow cleaning up solution was not helping.

Solution: deleted bin/debug folder and rebuild the entire solution fixed the issue.

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The *.dll* version in production machine and the *.dll* version in developing machine is different; reinstalling *.dll* will fix the problem.